# How to handle background image size shrink animation to "cover" properly in css?

Tags: css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I have the following div:

```css
.bg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("img/bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  animation: shrink-bg-img 1.5s;
}

@keyframes shrink-bg-img {
  0% {
    background-size: 110%;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 100%;
  }
}
```

It works fine in some viewport widths. I don't see the image edges at all. But it doesn't work fine in some viewport widths and I can see the image edges during the animation. (the image fits the width, so the top and bottom edges will be shown. The image is much smaller and then finally becomes big cover size in the end)

I tried `background-size: auto 100%;` and `background-size: auto 110%;`. It has the opposite results. I see the image edges for those tests I don't see it in the first case. And I don't see the image edges for those test I can see it in the first case.

Right now, I can fix it by using `@media` and use `auto` in some media width and do not use `auto` in some media width. But I have to do many tests to make sure it's working right.

Is there an easier solution to this problem?

Comment: Is this meta tag in your head section <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: @Is_this_my_username yeah, you are right, I actually have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`. Thanks. I need to support responsive design. This meta tag is in all my html codes.